# Which quadrilaterals $ABCD$ satisfy that triangles $ABC, BCD, CDA, DAB$ are similar

Tags: geometry

> Which quadrilaterals $ABCD$ satisfy that triangles $ABC, BCD, CDA, DAB$ are similar

I don't know where to start with this question. I tried to see which quadrilaterals satisfy the question and the only quadrilaterals that I found were parallelograms. So I tried to prove it but couldn't. I only managed to prove it for identical triangles. An issue I'm facing is that I do not know the ratios of similarity. Is it ${AB\over CD}$ or ${AB\over BC}$ and such. I tried to draw it and do some angle chasing but failed due to the reason stated earlier. I also tried to compare areas but failed. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Not all parallelograms qualify, but all rectangles do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The similarity of the triangles means that the angles $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ of the quadrilateral are all equal. Therefore the quadrilateral is a rectangle.